# No checked-in version files during content database migration

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-library

We're planning to migrate our SharePoint from 2013 to 2019 via 2016 bridge farm. Will documents with no-checked in version will migrate ? If I use sharegate or any third-party tool, it is mandated to check in the files .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check in the documents in order to migrate them along with the content database. You can use PowerShell to do the trick.

Here’s a sample script (**web application** scope) for your reference:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Set the Web application URL
$WebAppURL="<WAURL>"

#Get the Web Application       
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

#Get all Site collections from the web application
$SitesCollection  = $WebApp.Sites

#Enumerate all site collections in the web application
Foreach($Site in $SitesCollection) {

    #Loop through each sub-site of the site collection
    ForEach($Web in $Site.AllWebs) {
        Write-host -f Yellow "Searching for Checked out Files in Web:" $Web.Url

        #Loop through each list
        ForEach($List in $Web.Lists) {
            #Get Checked out files with no checkin versions
            $CheckedOutFiles = $List.CheckedOutFiles

            #Loop through each checked out File
            ForEach ($File in $CheckedOutFiles) {
                Write-Host -f Yellow "`t '$($File.LeafName)' at $($File.Url) is Checked out by: $($File.CheckedOutByName)"

                #Take ownership of the file
                $File.TakeOverCheckOut()

                #Check in the file
                $List.GetItemById($File.ListItemId).File.Checkin("Checked in by Administrator")
                Write-host -f Green "`t Took Ownership and Checked in the File!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [PowerShell to Manage Files Which Have No Checked in Version in SharePoint.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/07/powershell-to-manage-files-which-nave-no-checked-in-version.html)